# Class-based projections in with Spring Data JPA, CrudRepository

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

We have a working Repository implementation using DTO interface projections and CrudRepository.

I'd like to convert these DTO interfaces to DTO classes, since we need these to be serializable for our Redis cache. Spring Proxies for our interfaces don't have the required constructors expected for serialization/deserialization to the data store:

```
2023-01-18 15:13:28.949 ERROR 39286 [undedElastic-15] Error retrieving Mono value from redis cache: {}
org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.SerializationException: Could not read JSON: Cannot construct instance of `com.sun.proxy.$Proxy173` (no Creators, like default constructor, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
```

Unfortunately, I'm running into failures when Spring tries to convert query results to the new DTO's and I get errors like this one:

```
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.handleConverterNotFound(GenericConversionService.java:322)
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ Handler com.clickbank.clientanalytics.controller.AccountSalesHealthController#grossSalesByAffiliate(JwtAuthenticationToken, AnalyticsRequest) [DispatcherHandler]
```

Entity model (AccountSalesHealth):

```
/* Minimal table definition to use hibernate's CrudRepository */

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "mv_ca_account_sales_health")
public class AccountSalesHealth {
    @Id
    private Integer id;
}
```

Existing Repository interface:

```
public interface AccountSalesHealthRepository extends CrudRepository<AccountSalesHealth, String> {
    @Query(
            value = "select vendor_master_account as vendorMasterAccount" +
                    "     , vendor" +
                    "     , affiliate" +
                    "     , bus_date         as busDate" +
                    "     , sum(sale_amount) as amount " +
                    "from mv_ca_account_sales_health " +
                    "where vendor_master_account = :vendorMasterAccount" +
                    "  and bus_date >= :start" +
                    "  and bus_date <= :end " +
                    "group by 1, 3, 2, 4",
            nativeQuery = true
    )
    Collection<AccountSalesHealthDto> getGrossSalesByAffiliate(@Param("vendorMasterAccount") String vendorMasterAccount, @Param("start") String start, @Param("end") String end);
...
```

Old DTO class (this one works):

```
public interface AccountSalesHealthDto {
    String getVendorMasterAccount();

    String getVendor();

    String getBusDate();

    String getAffiliate();

    String getItemNo();

    Double getAmount();

    Double getAffAmount();

    Double getNetAmount();

    Integer getSaleCount();
}
```

After converting to a class:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class AccountSalesHealthDto {

    private String vendorMasterAccount;

    private String vendor;

    private String busDate;

    private String affiliate;

    private String itemNo;

    private Double amount;

    private Double affAmount;

    private Double netAmount;

    private Integer saleCount;
}
```

There are some notes [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-projections) about Class-Based Projections that would seem applicable, and this stood out as relevant:

> For a projection class to work in tandem with a repository interface,
> the parameter names of its constructor must match the properties of
> the root entity class.

I've tried a few things, none of which seem to have any effect:

- Add the other properties besides `Id` to the Entity class
- Overload DTO constructor such that the `Id` parameter is one of the arguments
- Generate the constructors instead of using Lombok annotations to specify the names of the constructor parameters.
- In addition to above, add `equals` and `hashCode` as called out in Section 4.

Have I missed anything?

Answer (score 2):

You probably missed the note in [Spring Data JPA documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections.dtos) which says:

> Class-based projections do not work with native queries AT ALL. As a
> workaround you may use named queries with `ResultSetMapping` or the
> Hibernate specific [`ResultTransformer`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/transform/ResultTransformer.html).

As suggested, you may use `@NamedNativeQuery` to define a native query and `@SqlResultSetMapping` to define the mapping of a native query result to a DTO class. For more details check [the blog post](https://thorben-janssen.com/spring-data-jpa-dto-native-queries/?fbclid=IwAR3wKXgqTcoIcM1RQFxFVKhoYxLzf3cxLQUgWHOymCfarO7_wDV_4Tzr5ro).